# bootstrap/modal: how to show page within it?

Tags: bootstrap-modal

I have a modal like below:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h3 class="modal-title">Modal Demo</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <a href="https://www.google.com">google</a>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

When the modal pops up and I click "google", I expect to see the page shown within the modal. Is it possible? I don't have to use modal but would like solution "compatible" with bootstrap.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: yes , it is possible to show page in modal , let me give you answer in brief,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Put this code in HTML

```
<div class="modal fade bs-modal-sm" id="modal"  role="dialog"  aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Jquery Function

```
function show_modal(target, title, size) {
    jQuery('#modal').removeData('bs.modal');
    jQuery('.modal-content').html('');
    jQuery('.modal-dialog').removeClass('modal-lg');
    jQuery('#modal').removeClass('create_event_task');
    jQuery('.modal-dialog').addClass(size);
    var newTarget = target.indexOf("?") >= 0 ? target + '&modal-title=' + title : target + '?modal-title=' + title;
    jQuery('#modal').modal({remote: encodeURI(newTarget)});
}
```

> Call JQuery function , using `Onclick` event.

```
show_modal('admin_users', 'Delete User', '');
```

I am using this function for open a page within my application , you can try it using a URL.

Hope this answer is helpful to you.

Comment: Great, thanks! I don't have time right now, but I will give it shot later. Just one quick question in case you know: suppose google page shows up in modal and I click one of its search results, will the target page also in the modal?

Comment: I am sorry it doesn't really work as I test. It works when the target is from the same server, but not when I use https://www.google.com. You can check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/jh3obbp0/. Thanks.

Comment: @user180574 , that thing i also said in my answer, it is working for within my application.

Comment: @user180574 , the problem is cross origin check this error in console `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.com/. Redirect from 'https://www.google.com/' to 'https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=ghRfWbibO7PT8gfk3LD4Cg' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: Thanks, although your answer doesn't solve my problem (which may not be solvable anyway), I do appreciate your help and clarification!